# Bootstrap Navbar Animation cuts of Input fields

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap NavBar that is collapsible.  I have two elements inside the collapsible `<div>`,

`<form class="form-inline>` and `<select class="custom-select" id="menu">`

(See my code)

My issue is that when I open the collapsible area, the two elements are briefly cut off and then quickly align themselves under the NavBar-Brand (You can see this happening [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wheqbu9p/2/)).  I don't know how to deal with this, because I need those two elements to be left aligned with the Brand in the navbar, but I haven't been able to figure out a solution.  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Airforce Inventory Information Database</a>
            <!--<button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar9">-->
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar9" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </button>

            <!--<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar9">-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar9">
                <div class="interior">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <form class="form-inline" data-toggle="#octopart" action="http://octopart.com/search" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search Octopart ..." name="search" style="width: 45%;"> 
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" data_target="#octopart" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </form>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3"  data-toggle="#parts" style="width: 35%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Devices</label>
                            </div>
                            <select class="custom-select" id="menu">
                                <option value='capacitors'>Capacitors</a></option>
                                <option value='inductors'>Inductors</a></option>
                                <option value='resistors'>Resistors</a></option>
                                <option value='miscellaneous'>Miscellaneous</a></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </nav>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with those negative left and right margins?

Comment: The bootstrap navbar operates with negative margins, at least empirically that's what I've discovered, I'm not sure why.  I need the elements within the drop down to be left aligned with the title in the navbar

Answer (score 0):

```
.interior {margin-left: -12.5%;}
```

Please remove this css. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I know it prevents the graphically clipping, but it doesn't solve my problem which is that I need the two elements to be left aligned with the title in the navbar upon opening (Like how they eventually appear once the graphical clipping stops)